# Qunit test cases for javascript logging

Tags: javascript, qunit

I am working on javascript client logging.I have function in JavaScript called WriteLog,which basically post a message to specified server URL and also write a message/exception to console.log,console.error and console.warn(if available).

I am looking for reference how to write qunit testing cases for WriteLog function

Any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You should use a stub or a spy function and watch that it have been called with the right parameters.

Checkout [Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) (and [specific to Sinon.js and QUnit](http://sinonjs.org/qunit/))